# I can't get a transition effect inside a dropdown to work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to transition effect for my menu's dropdown, but unlike the other cases, I can't manage to get it work.
I've search lots of theards around here and over google as well. I found no solution.

Here's my code:

```
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    top: 34px;
    transition: height 2s;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
    display: block;
}


.dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

HTML:

```
                <div class="menu_option dropdown2"><a href="?go=articles">articles</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content2">
                        <a href="?go=news">news</a>
                        <a href="?go=reviews">reviews</a>
                        <a href="?go=guides">guides</a>
                        <a href="?go=art">art</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please add your html here

Comment: Can you provide a working example that showcase your current problem?

Comment: sorry. included html on my original post now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try like this.. in display none and block transition effect not working.. so now i changed opacity

**HTML**

```
   <div class="menu_option dropdown2"><a href="?go=כתבות">כל הכתבות</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content2">
                        <a href="?go=news">news</a>
                        <a href="?go=reviews">reviews</a>
                        <a href="?go=guides">guides</a>
                        <a href="?go=art">art</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**css**

```
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
   opacity:0;
   visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    top: 34px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
    opacity:1;
   visibility:visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease
}


.dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work as well. :(
also, I would like to know where i'm wrong please.

Comment: pls share working example.. here css all are fine.. you try to add hover:transition: height 2s;.. i changed code again.. pls check now

Comment: I've have added some info into my original post now

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: pls check now.. if you use display:none and block transition effect not work

Comment: Now it works! thank you! where were I go wrong?

Comment: your code is correct.. when you use display none for submenus after hover block the content transition effect  not work

Comment: Noted. thank you so much!

Comment: cool.. welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't transition from `display: none` to `display: block`.

Fortunately, in this case you don't need to. You only need to transition from `height: 0` to `height: 220px`.

**N.B.** You *also* need to ensure that `.dropdown-content2` has the style `overflow: hidden` to ensure that when the content of the parent element exceeds the height, it does not overflow the boundaries and reveal itself.

**Working Example:**

```css
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    color: #000;
    min-width: 150px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    top: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}

.dropdown2 .dropdown-content2 {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 2s;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
    height: 220px;
}


.dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_option dropdown2"><a href="?go=articles">articles</a>
<div class="dropdown-content2">
<a href="?go=news">news</a>
<a href="?go=reviews">reviews</a>
<a href="?go=guides">guides</a>
<a href="?go=art">art</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know. thank you very much for pointing my mistake and help me :)

Comment: Please upvote and accept if the answer above resolves your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to SO, it won't let me as I need more rep :(